# How to implement Joi validation in hapi.js?

Tags: node.js, joi, hapi.js

I just want to implement `Joi` in `Hapi` API.

```
server.route([
    {
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/login',
        config: {
            tags: ['login', 'auth'],
            auth: false,
            validate: {
                payload: payloadValidator,
                failAction: (req, h, source, error) => {                                                
                    console.log("Error ::: ", source.details[0].message);
                    return h.response({ code: 0, message: source.details[0].message });                        
                }
            }
        },
        handler: async (request, h) => {
            console.log(request.payload.email);
            console.log(request.payload.password);
            ...                                
        }
    }
]);
```

Hear I call `payloadValidator`.

```
const payloadValidator = Joi.object({
    email: Joi.string().required(),
    password: Joi.string().required()
}).options({ allowUnknown: true });
```

Actually I'm new with `hapi` and I'm missing something in my code. Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

**Required output**

If I do not pass `email` then the app must throw an error of `Email is required` and it should be the same with the `password` field also.

**Error:**

`Error :::  "email" is required
Debug: internal, implementation, error 
    Error: Lifecycle methods called before the handler can only return an error, a takeover response, or a continue signal
    at Request._lifecycle (/var/www/html/hapi/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/request.js:326:33)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an error suggests **Lifecycle methods called before the handler can only return an error, a takeover response, or a continue signal** you have to return takeover response.

```
return h.response({ code: 0, message: source.details[0].message }).takeover();
```

For more information you can visit this link : [reference link](https://medium.com/@piotrkarpaa/handling-joi-validation-errors-in-hapi-17-26fc07448576)